# Administratively accessing end users' blocked senders list

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I am an Email Administrator at my University and the office that sends out student updates feels like many of the students have blocked them. They want us to see how many people have blocked them.

We are on an Exchange 2007 Server for faculty and live@edu for students.
We are running PowerShell Version 2.0

So my question is:
Is there a way administratively getting end users' "Blocked Senders" list (from Outlook) using 
Exchange or a PowerShell script?

(Short of remotely accessing each student and checking their blocked list)

I have found nothing about this anywhere, I'm guessing that means you can't?

The news letter has important announcements like intramural sports events...

Comment: Ahh, college students. That's why many of them don't get jobs, because they don't care. If there is not a PowerShell module for Exchange 2007 you might try [Web Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) their accounts with OWA. Can you use a COM object to play with Exchange?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm somewhat new to this job so I'm still learning. I will have to look into web scraping and COM objects. I'm pretty sure we do use COM objects but I don't fully understand that yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [`Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979784%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet should be able to provide what you are looking for here.

(I realize this is an old question - but for anyone else who may find this and be looking for a solution...)

I'm not sure about Exchange 2007 (an anonymous editor reports that this does not work in 2007), but this at least works under Exchange 2010.  ([Exchange 2007 went into extended support on 2012-04-10, with extended support ending on 2017-04-11.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mr_proactive/2012/05/10/support-lifecycle-and-products-you-need-to-consider-upgrading/))

Here is what the raw command can provide:

```
[PS] C:\>Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration someUsername


RunspaceId               : 900f7cb7-3cae-4335-895b-ccf1a04fa09d
Enabled                  : True
TrustedListsOnly         : False
ContactsTrusted          : False
TrustedSendersAndDomains : {}
BlockedSendersAndDomains : {}
MailboxOwnerId           : some.domain/SOME-OU/someUserName
Identity                 : some.domain/SOME-OU/someUserName
IsValid                  : True
```

Obviously, replace `someUsername` with an appropriate username.  Note that the test user here currently doesn't have any blocks configured.

To get only the `BlockedSendersAndDomains` attribute:

```
(Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration someUsername).BlockedSendersAndDomains
```